# Prove a randomly indexed random sequence converges in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n\to X$ in distribution, $\{N_t,t\ge 0\}$ is a collection of $\Bbb  Z_+$-valued random variables such that $N_t\to+\infty$ in probability, and $(N_t)$ are independent of $(X_n)$. Show that $X_{N_t}\to X$ in distribution as $t\to+\infty$.

I think we have to deal with the CDF definition of convergence in distribution i.e. $F_n(x)\to F(x)$ weakly (meaning on the set of continuities of $F$) where $F_n,F$ are CDFs of $X_n,X$ respectively. But how go relate $F_n$ to $F_{N_t}$ to pass the convergence through?

Thanks.

Comment: As such, the result is wrong. What is your source?

Comment: @Did it's from a contest. I'll check gain.

Comment: @Did sorry, should have added $N_t$ are independent of $X_n$.

Comment: Indeed you should have. And now surely you have an idea about how to start?

Comment: @Did I believe I'm on the right track. I'll give it a try when I wake up tomorrow. By the way what's your counterexample when there is no independence?

Comment: @Did: I would also be interested in a counterexample, when independence fails. Any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$,
$$
\mathsf{E}f(X_{N(t)})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathsf{E}f(X_{k})\mathsf{P}(N(t)=k).
$$
Given $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $K$ and $T$ large enough s.t. $\lvert \mathsf{E}f(X_{k})-\mathsf{E}f(X)\rvert\le\epsilon$ and $\mathsf{P}(N(t)\le K)\le \epsilon$ for all $k\ge K$ and $t\ge T$. Then
\begin{align}
\lvert\mathsf{E}f(X_{N(t)})-\mathsf{E}f(X)\rvert &\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert \mathsf{E}f(X_{k})-\mathsf{E}f(X)\rvert\mathsf{P}(N(t)=k) \\
&\le \sum_{k=1}^K \lvert\mathsf{E}f(X_{k})-\mathsf{E}f(X)\rvert\mathsf{P}(N(t)=k) \\
&+ \sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty}\lvert \mathsf{E}f(X_{k})-\mathsf{E}f(X)\rvert\mathsf{P}
(N(t)=k) \\
&\le 2C\mathsf{P}(N(t)\le K)+\epsilon\le C'\epsilon,
\end{align}
where $C,C'>0$ are some constants.