# Given weak convergence, can I take a random sequence and still get convergence in distribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I have a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ with values subgraphs of $G$ (which we model by samples as random functions in $\{0,1\}^{E(G)}$) indexed by $\mathbb N$, yielding corresponding measures $\mu_n$, which converge weakly to some $\mu$, (which is defined as (realising there is normally a more measure-theoretic definition) as
$$
\mu_n(C) \to \mu(C)
$$
for all $C$ cylinder events.

I then have (not independent) $(N_n)$ that is a.s. increasing that defines a random subsequence of measures
$$
\mu_{N_n} := \mathbb P(X_{N_n} \sim C)
$$
where I'm writing $X_n \sim C$ as equality on the support of $C:E(G) \to \{0,1\}$.

I'm trying to figure out whether it is possible to say something in a general case about convergence of this subsequence?

In the independent case, taking a product measure and first evaluating the random measure to get convergence for all $C$ cylinder events would work well.

(Looking around I also found [Prove a randomly indexed random sequence converges in distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310827/prove-a-randomly-indexed-random-sequence-converges-in-distribution), but in this case we have a sequence indexed by reels and worse converge - only convergence in probability to infinity where I have an almost surely increasing sequence, and I don't have independence here which would allow the product measure to be easily used)